# Output not showing in my ubuntu while compiling c

Tags: c++, c, output

While compiling my C code in sublime-text in my Ubuntu The output is not shown.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCDjd.png)

Comment: There is not normally any output during compile if there are no errors or warnings. (I only use command line compile, but assume it is the same for what you are using). You would have to execute the compiled program to get the "Hello world!" output.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: How to run that file to see output?

Answer (score 3):

I do not use sublime-text, and do not know how to answer using it.
If you have the build-essentials package installed then here is an example command compile then execute of your program (I already have a hello.c, so used hello1.c):

```
doug@s19:~/c$ cat hello1.c
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
   int a;
   printf("Hello world!");
}
doug@s19:~/c$ cc hello1.c -o hello1
doug@s19:~/c$ ./hello1
Hello world!doug@s19:~/c$
```

But I would have put a newline at the end of the print and deleted the unused variable. So:

```
doug@s19:~/c$ cat hello1.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
   printf("Hello world!\n");
}
doug@s19:~/c$ cc hello1.c -o hello1
doug@s19:~/c$ ./hello1
Hello world!
doug@s19:~/c$
```